# How can you request photo gallery permissions in iOS a second time

Tags: ios, permissions, privacy

In my iOS app I am accessing the user's photo gallery.  The first time the user does this, it asks them for permission.  Some of my users have reported getting a crash this first time due to the permission request, but it works fine on subsequent tries.

To be able to test this on my own, I need to be able remove the permission from my iPad and have it prompt again.  Is there a way to do this either through the iPad/iPhone itself or through code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the Settings app. Go to General, then Reset. Tap on Reset Location & Privacy. This will reset all of your location and privacy settings, not just for your test app. But you are doing this on a development device so that should be OK. This works in the Simulator too.

Comment: Well, this looks like it is the best way to do it.  It would be much better if I could clear it off without having to clear any other applications, but you gotta do what Apple wants you to do sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 7+, you can go into Settings > Privacy > Photos and explicitly enable or disable access for individual apps.

This is much better than resetting your entire device privacy settings!

Comment: But this doesn't answer the question. This simply changes the app's setting. It doesn't allow the app to show the permission dialog again which is what the question is asking.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to temporary change Bundle Identifier (CFBundleIdentifier) in Info.plist.
System will treat such app as a new separate app and will display "would like to access your Photos" alert.
Don't forget to revert CFBundleIdentifier after you end testing.