# iOS MapKit not asking for location permissions

Tags: ios, location, mapkit

It seems that once the user has denied the application permission to locate her on the map, any subsequent call to `[locationManager startUpdatingLocation]` will fail, but will not automatically prompt the user to set the correct permission in the settings as the iPhone map app does.

Is this behavior intended on iOS6, or is there a way to force MapKit to ask the user again for permission to use her location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is intended. Once the user denied the permission then you can't ask it each time your app starts, if it do it'll be very annoying to user.

If user wants to give permission later, he need to go to settings app and set the necessary permission.

It's same for all type of permissions like location service, push notification, contact permission, photolibrary etc.

Comment: But in my case I am requesting it only when the user wants to locate herself on a map, a bit like the iPhone map apps (which does the link to the Settings panel), is that not possible?

Comment: It'll ask only one time, you can't prompt second time for any permissions.

Comment: @oulipo: I read it somewhere, i'll check that, and provide that link

Comment: @oulipo Please check these links also, similar issues http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13969544/ios-photo-permissions-to-ask-for-second-time, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916721/how-can-you-request-photo-gallery-permissions-in-ios-a-second-time

Answer (score 0):

You should use the delegate method locationManager:didFailWithError: and look for a kCLErrorDenied.