# Reset "<App> would like to access your photos" dialog on iOS

Tags: ios, testing, dialog

For testing purposes, I need to make sure that my app handles trying to access the user's photos correctly for all scenarios.

Once the user is presented with the dialog asking for access to the photos, the user won't ever be presented with it again for that app…at least I can't figure out how they could be.

Obviously if the user selects "YES" then access is granted and will continue as such unless the settings are changed in the user's Settings app. Alternatively, if "NO" is chosen, you won't have access until those same settings are changed.

But for testing, I want to make sure that my app handles either scenario correctly when the user is first presented with the dialog. I seem to only be able to test this once though. After that, there doesn't seem to be any way to show this dialog again. Somehow, even if the app is deleted and reinstalled, the option chosen when first presented is remembered and the dialog is never shown.

The only way I can test it over again is to change the bundle identifier, clean and run the app again. This essentially installs another or "new" app on the device and the dialog is shown. This is kind of a long work around for testing purposes. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can you request photo gallery permissions in iOS a second time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916721/how-can-you-request-photo-gallery-permissions-in-ios-a-second-time)

Comment: I believe you're right. I searched this question before asking but to be quite honest, that's a pretty strange way the question was worded in the linked post. (It certainly never came up in any of my searches). Thanks for pointing it out though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to:

```
Settings > General > Reset > Reset Location & Privacy
```

[image]

Comment: I wish there was some way of doing this without messing with the other apps on my phone, but oh well.